# Add 1 to value as rank increases

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with some grouped ranked data that has a latitude and longitude I would like to add 0.00075 to the latitude field every time the rank increases 1.

Below is one of the 5000 groups and it is unknown what the max rack will be so I need this to with within a group_by ideally using dplyr.

I know I can use a

```r
group_by(loc_id) %>% mutate(y = if_else(rank > 1, as.character(Y + 0.00075), as.character(Y))
```

but this only works one time.

Here is some r code to build a dataframe full of data

```r
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
loc_id <- c(77,77,77,77,77)
x <- c(-74.001981, -74.001981, -74.001981, -74.001981, -74.001981)
y <- c(40.736038, 40.736038, 40.736038, 40.736038, 40.736038)
views <- c(55,45,66,22,99)
rank <- c(3,4,2,5,1)
data <- data.frame(id, loc_id, x, y, views, rank)
```

Comment: What do you meant by one-time.  if it is grouped by 'loc_id' it should change the values for each group.  Also, you have provided data only for a single 'loc_id', so not clear what you meant

Comment: It changes all values with rank greater 1 need it to loop so that every row in the group has a different latitude increasing by 0.00075 as the rank goes up.

Comment: Can't you just do `data %>%
 group_by(loc_id) %>%
 mutate(y = y + ((rank - 1) * 0.00075))`?

Comment: Thank you @tmfmnk I've never see that. Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into a post. Using `dplyr`, you can do:

```
data %>% 
 group_by(loc_id) %>% 
 mutate(y = y + ((rank - 1) * 0.00075))
```